# How to convert Scala class object to jSON and manipulate a dependent object?

Tags: scala, playframework

Say I want the following Json:

```
   {
      "client": "some-client",
      "target": "some-target",
      "function": "some-function",
      "arg": {
        "doer": "machine",
        "path": {
          "machine": { "application": "some-application",
                       "env": "some-env",
                       "machines": {"A": "Do something", "B": "Do more"}
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

How can I make a case class structure to result in the above jSON?

Here is what I have tried, say I have the following case classes:

```
case class MachinePayload
(
  client    : String,
  target    : String,
  function  : String,
  arg       : Arg

)

case class Arg
(
  doer : String,
  path : ArgPath
)

case class ArgPath
(
  application : String,
  env         : String,
  machines    : List[Machine]
)

case class Machine
(
  id       : Long,
  name     : String,
  function : String
)
```

And say we create some MachinePayload:

```
MachinePayload(
 client = "some-client",
 target = "some-target",
 function = "some-function",
 arg = Arg(
   doer = "machine",
   path = ArgPath(
     application = "some-application",
     environment = "some-env",
     machines = List(Machine(id = 1, name = "A", function = "Do Something"), Machine(id = 2, name = "B", function = "Do More"))
   )
 )
)
```

As you can see what is the best way to convert `ArgPath` using `play.api.libs.json` to the desired structure in the jSON above, and place it in a key "machine".  There is likely a smarter a way to structure these classes maybe creating another case class that has the "machine" field in it and making it `Map[String, Any]`?

Comment: Why dont you define implicit Json formats for each case classes

Comment: @geek94 Yea, had to define implicit jSON formats using the `play.api.libs.json` library.  And instead of List(Machine), had to define it as `Map[String, String]` in a new case class and do that `List(Machine)` to `Map[String, String]` conversion outside.

Answer (score 0):

The following uses Circe and its `semiauto` derivation to save most of the boilerplate. You can certainly change specific things as needed.

The main concept is that you implement a pair of implicit `Encoder` and `Decoder` for each type in your ADT and then the encoding and decoding steps will take care of finding what's needed to complete. Another nice thing about Circe's parsing approach is that potential failures are encoded in the result type (e.g. `Either[Error,A]`).

```
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe._
import io.circe.generic.semiauto._
import io.circe.jawn._

object objs{
  case class MachinePayload(
    client    : String,
    target    : String,
    function  : String,
    arg       : Arg
  )
  object MachinePayload{
    implicit def jsonDecoder : Decoder[MachinePayload] = deriveDecoder
    implicit def jsonEncoder : Encoder[MachinePayload] = deriveEncoder
  }

  case class Arg(
    doer : String,
    path : ArgPath
  )
  object Arg{
    implicit def jsonDecoder : Decoder[Arg] = deriveDecoder
    implicit def jsonEncoder : Encoder[Arg] = deriveEncoder
  }

  case class ArgPath(
    application : String,
    env         : String,
    machines    : List[Machine]
  )
  object ArgPath{
    implicit def jsonDecoder : Decoder[ArgPath] = deriveDecoder
    implicit def jsonEncoder : Encoder[ArgPath] = deriveEncoder
  }

  case class Machine(
    id       : Long,
    name     : String,
    function : String
  )
  object Machine{
    implicit def jsonDecoder : Decoder[Machine] = deriveDecoder
    implicit def jsonEncoder : Encoder[Machine] = deriveEncoder
  }
}

import objs._

val test = MachinePayload(
  client = "some-client",
  target = "some-target",
  function = "some-function",
  arg = Arg(
    doer = "machine",
    path = ArgPath(
      application = "some-application",
      env = "some-env",
      machines = List(Machine(id = 1, name = "A", function = "Do Something"), Machine(id = 2, name = "B", function = "Do More"))
    )
  )
)

val strJson = test.asJson.spaces2

parse(strJson).flatMap(_.as[MachinePayload])
```

The resulting json is the following:

```
{
  "client" : "some-client",
  "target" : "some-target",
  "function" : "some-function",
  "arg" : {
    "doer" : "machine",
    "path" : {
      "application" : "some-application",
      "env" : "some-env",
      "machines" : [
        {
          "id" : 1,
          "name" : "A",
          "function" : "Do Something"
        },
        {
          "id" : 2,
          "name" : "B",
          "function" : "Do More"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that the `List[Machine]` needs to be an json array, because you don't know how many elements there are going to be from the type.